# editing cr2 files

Tags: canon, raw

I'm having trouble with some of my images. some of them wont upload to pixieset. and I have these xmp files on my cameras memory card. none of the platforms i use to upload will support the files. they look fine on the usb I have to mail to the client but I dont want them to have a problem trying to print them out... I hope I explained this good enough. I've never had this problem. any help will be appreciated. They are .CR2 images if that helps.

Comment: Have you contacted your client to find out what file format they desire? Do they want raw files or finished images?

Comment: If you need to transmit those files, why not doing ftp, or a simple hosting or a wetransfer ?

Answer (score -2):

Edit the image and save them as TIFF or JPEG, then mail them to the client.

Comment: Really this answer needs considerably more detail. The OP obviously doesn't know what a sidecar file is, or how to deal with it, so giving them an output format with no procedure is not going to help them. [I can't provide an alternative answer myself, as I deal in NEF, not CR2]